# How to solve a large system of nonlinear equations in MATLAB or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

## Description of problem

I'm trying to solve system of nonlinear equations:

- I have 60 equations (variations of 3 equations with measured data substituted in), and 10 complex-valued unknowns (broken down into 20 magnitude/phase unknowns).
- magnitudes are specified in dB, should be real values bound between -80 and 0, labeled s11db,s21db,s22db,s31db,s32db,s33db,s41db,s42db,s43db,s44db
- phases are specified in radians, should be real values bound between 0 and 2*pi, labeled s11ph,s21ph,s22ph,s31ph,s32ph,s33ph,s41ph,s42ph,s43ph,s44ph
- 4 additional constraint equations enforce passivity

  - `|s11|^2+|s21|^2+|s31|^2+|s41|^2 <= 1`
  - `|s21|^2+|s22|^2+|s32|^2+|s42|^2 <= 1`
  - `|s31|^2+|s32|^2+|s33|^2+|s43|^2 <= 1`
  - `|s41|^2+|s42|^2+|s43|^2+|s44|^2 <= 1`
- the equations are:

  - `((s11 * (1 - (s43 * Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 + s33 * Γ1 + s44 *  Γ2) (s33 * Γ1 * s44 * Γ2)) + s31 * Γ1 * s31 * (1-(s44 * Γ2)) + s31 * Γ1 * s43 * Γ2 * s41 + s41 * Γ2 * s41 * (1-( s33 * Γ1)) + s41 * Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 * s31) / (1 - (s43 *  Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 + s33 * Γ1 + s44 * Γ2) + (s33 * Γ1 * s44 * Γ2)) = s11p`
  - `eq2 = (s32*Γ1*s31*(1-(s44*Γ2)+0)+s32*Γ1*s43*Γ2*s41+s42*Γ2 *s41*(1-(s33*Γ1))+s42*Γ2*s43*Γ1*s31+s21*(1 -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2))) / (1 -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2)) = s21p`
  - `eq3 = (s32*Γ1*s32*(1-(s44*Γ2)+0)+s32*Γ1*s43*Γ2*s42*(1-0+0)+s22*(1 -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2))+s42*Γ2* s42*(1-(s33*Γ1)+0)+s42*Γ2*s43*Γ1*s32*(1-0+0)) / (1 -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2)) = s22p`

## What I've tried so far

I've tried to attack this problem with sympy's nsolve function, and also (after a bit of finagling), MATLAB's fsolve and lsqnonlin functions, but I haven't had much luck with it. nsolve bailed with an error, and besides that I wasn't able to find a way to bound the results. MATLAB on the other hand stopped almost instantly, and returned something that was very close to any guess I put in for the starting point - while the values were bound in some sense, it tried to return complex numbers for things that I specified real bounds for, so I'm not sure what's up with that.

### An attempt in Python

my attempt in python looked like this - I've stripped down the problem and included just enough of the dataset to be able to run the script - obfuscating the bits where data is read in and processed, and the fact that this is going to run ~1000 times in a loop with slightly different data corresponding to measurements at other frequencies.

```py
    import sympy
    from sympy.core.power import Pow
    from sympy import I as j
    from sympy import Rel,Eq,Abs,nsolve
    import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        # these are real valued.
        s11db,s21db,s22db,s31db,s32db,s33db,s41db,s42db,s43db,s44db=sympy.symbols('s11db s21db s22db s31db s32db s33db s41db s42db s43db s44db',real=True)
        s11ph,s21ph,s22ph,s31ph,s32ph,s33ph,s41ph,s42ph,s43ph,s44ph=sympy.symbols('s11ph s21ph s22ph s31ph s32ph s33ph s41ph s42ph s43ph s44ph',real=True)
        s11,s21,s22,s31,s32,s33,s41,s42,s43,s44=sympy.symbols('s11 s21 s22 s22 s31 s33 s41 s42 s43 s44')

        variablesdb=[s11db,s21db,s22db,s31db,s32db,s33db,s41db,s42db,s43db,s44db]
        variablesph=[s11ph,s21ph,s22ph,s31ph,s32ph,s33ph,s41ph,s42ph,s43ph,s44ph]
        variables = []
        variables.extend(variablesdb)
        variables.extend(variablesph)

        guessesdb=[-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20,-20]
        guessesph = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        guesses = []
        guesses.extend(guessesdb)
        guesses.extend(guessesph)

        s11 = Pow(10,(s11db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s11ph)
        s21 = Pow(10,(s21db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s21ph)
        s22 = Pow(10,(s22db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s22ph)
        s31 = Pow(10,(s31db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s31ph)
        s32 = Pow(10,(s32db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s32ph)
        s33 = Pow(10,(s33db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s33ph)
        s41 = Pow(10,(s41db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s41ph)
        s42 = Pow(10,(s42db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s42ph)
        s43 = Pow(10,(s43db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s43ph)
        s44 = Pow(10,(s44db/10)) * sympy.exp(j*s44ph)
        mΓ1=[0.016748068572860958+0.02165573563670993j,\
            0.3524499197684044+1.01318272809286j, \
            0.9902384965572285-0.4090088119125726j,\
            0.9902384965572285-0.4090088119125726j,\
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j,\
            0.8481899405540196-0.6521365553445038j,\
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j,\
            0.8483474812536963-0.6520564750063542j,\
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j,\
            0.844854651665744-0.6565142490941961j,\
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j,\
            0.8596032944139899-0.6370905579072205j,\
            0.12178304066817838+0.23419002409258938j,\
            0.25810610017732+0.11233917791430391j,\
            -0.7881852138612478+0.2941231164148775j,\
            0.8537371705084078+0.46722896692551863j,\
            0.14050135652671147+0.3073232683089746j,\
            0.09456025715651947+0.3638487655929115j,\
            0.7994228601750994+0.36132988231302926j,\
            -0.5729577316366177+0.3829110562916974j]
        mΓ2=[0.01886638946281557+0.02291153736938316j,\
            0.41115632130362006+0.9904544135078267j,\
            -1.0602110266293787+0.12873002023570793j,\
            -1.0602110266293787+0.12873002023570793j,\
            0.12178304066817838+0.23419002409258938j,\
            0.25810610017732+0.11233917791430391j,\
            -0.7881852138612478+0.2941231164148775j,\
            0.8537371705084078+0.46722896692551863j,\
            0.14050135652671147+0.3073232683089746j,\
            0.09456025715651947+0.3638487655929115j,\
            0.7994228601750994+0.36132988231302926j,\
            -0.5729577316366177+0.3829110562916974j,\
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j,\
            0.8481899405540196-0.6521365553445038j,\
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j,\
            0.8483474812536963-0.6520564750063542j,\
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j,\
            0.844854651665744-0.6565142490941961j,\
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j,\
            0.8596032944139899-0.6370905579072205j]
        ms11p=[-0.06420852176004949+0.007606136138496574j,\
              -0.537896794882235+0.4041100722456898j,\
              0.1412012055714567+0.5635279161255173j,\
              0.1937727600367866+0.4292234886620929j,\
              0.1469515332766462+0.5314862612846253j,\
              0.1518709241016716+0.5310052159365275j,\
              0.1578520689668907+0.5331598663019053j,\
              0.1540581804228726+0.5392467784421259j,\
              0.1431331385368337+0.5325073157781589j,\
              0.1535928910517443+0.5342246999907136j,\
              0.1512448255547076+0.5392322097605335j,\
              0.1473241418663376+0.5318193110512432j,\
              -0.2363809027693515+0.1174058767406709j,\
              -0.163391416393593+0.08774117501580507j,\
              -0.4568108580888767-0.2143100180166485j,\
              0.193345944206058-0.04761628164099008j,\
              -0.237571999125396+0.1195031741294373j,\
              -0.2034191332391219+0.1681349627984851j,\
              0.03011118465025885-0.09412680418431373j,\
              -0.04464063283385059+0.3528230797332958j]
        ms21p=[-0.003180197204485371-0.002823666341755482j,\
              -0.1906367035405745+0.0686968862920421j,\
              -0.05526246736964503+0.02635489796438511j,\
              0.002518013584325512+0.06590835456839306j,\
              -0.03537661863079149+0.08706407624479129j,\
              -0.01805052294769753+0.08243849033759301j,\
              -0.07056927627440178+0.03869620150023408j,\
              0.02738173375006136+0.04029812368020189j,\
              -0.02971165660146774+0.08491907637374546j,\
              -0.02737424760484992+0.09187392180460466j,\
              0.001038602543646932+0.03696165082008047j,\
              0.01181224381379054+0.1271817903117702j,\
              -0.03214857971468995+0.1284805218320462j,\
              -0.01717410586879602+0.1297380448848506j,\
              -0.03433798336733016+0.06369364773628092j,\
              0.043654417400282+0.1396753864320528j,\
              -0.03468050284302436+0.1289630391584528j,\
              -0.03705274246077175+0.1366485542793229j,\
              0.02030699854620357+0.1217902270543576j,\
              -0.0236005339029794+0.1770862461678967j]
        ms22p=[-0.1624942212974896-0.004693967380702952j,\
              -0.284542316854743-0.7064738951728178j,\
              0.4536543123936424-0.4578177740567013j,\
              -0.1024338501849106-0.1979272945233151j,\
              -0.1097995580875526-0.198389196010508j,\
              -0.07902213390718082-0.08677717201029744j,\
              0.3602007967821697-0.4162898752449462j,\
              0.1822099768155973+0.3712680606767835j,\
              -0.09809454238916153-0.1552338582896147j,\
              -0.1688279742308047-0.115960920204985j,\
              0.2331637616249181+0.1528931729845114j,\
              -0.4800053258074745+0.09873053685139994j,\
              -0.7738872200476685-0.04023055998635539j,\
              -0.7721863083906342-0.02871292187380659j,\
              -0.7821436668003945-0.03478684929877463j,\
              -0.7693920578775125-0.04497757228074708j,\
              -0.7737959107116188-0.03930039783428967j,\
              -0.7721735572720234-0.03995110444341842j,\
              -0.7729703027226912-0.04204217380573128j,\
              -0.766856877704361-0.04045169338481738j]
        equations = [] # sympy equations
    #    equations.append(Rel(s11db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s21db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s22db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s31db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s32db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s33db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s41db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s42db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s43db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s44db,0,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s11db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s21db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s22db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s31db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s32db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s33db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s41db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s42db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s43db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s44db,-80,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s11ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s21ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s22ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s31ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s32ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s33ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s41ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s42ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s43ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s44ph,0,'>='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s11ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s21ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s22ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s31ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s32ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s33ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s41ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s42ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s43ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))
    #    equations.append(Rel(s44ph,2*sympy.pi,'<='))

        for n in range(len(mΓ1)):
            Γ1 = mΓ1[n]
            Γ2 = mΓ2[n]
            s11p = ms11p[n]
            s21p = ms21p[n]
            s22p = ms22p[n]

            eq1 = Eq(((s11 * (1 - (s43 * Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 + s33 * Γ1 + s44 *  Γ2) \
                + (s33 * Γ1 * s44 * Γ2)) + s31 * Γ1 * s31 * (1-(s44 * Γ2)) \
                + s31 * Γ1 * s43 * Γ2 * s41 + s41 * Γ2 * s41 * (1-( s33 * Γ1))\
                + s41 * Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 * s31) / (1 - (s43 *  Γ2 * s43 * Γ1 \
                + s33 * Γ1 + s44 * Γ2) + (s33 * Γ1 * s44 * Γ2))),
                    s11p, evaluate=False)
            eq2 = Eq((s32*Γ1*s31*(1-(s44*Γ2)+0)+s32*Γ1*s43*Γ2*s41+s42*Γ2 \
                   *s41*(1-(s33*Γ1))+s42*Γ2*s43*Γ1*s31+s21*(1 \
                   -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2))) / (1 \
                   -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2)),
                        s21p, evaluate=False)
            eq3 = Eq((s32*Γ1*s32*(1-(s44*Γ2)+0)+s32*Γ1*s43*Γ2*s42*(1-0+0)+s22*(1 \
                   -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2))+s42*Γ2* \
                   s42*(1-(s33*Γ1)+0)+s42*Γ2*s43*Γ1*s32*(1-0+0)) / (1 \
                   -(s43*Γ2*s43*Γ1+s33*Γ1+s44*Γ2)+(s33*Γ1*s44*Γ2)),
                       s22p, evaluate=False)
            equations.append(eq1)
            equations.append(eq2)
            equations.append(eq3)

        print(nsolve(equations,variables,guesses))
        sys.exit(0)


    # would like to add the following constraints:
    # between one frequency and the next, dB value should be fairly stable
    # probably not more than a few dB of variation, phase value should be stable
    # too

    # dB values should be constrained between -80dB and 0dB
    # phase values should be constrained between 0 and 2π
    # low loss passivity conditions:
    # |s11|^2 + |s21|^2 + |s31|^2 + |s41|^2 <= 1 (should be close to 1 if low loss)
    # |s21|^2 + |s22|^2 + |s32|^2 + |s42|^2 <= 1 (should be close to 1 if low loss)
    # |s31|^2 + |s32|^2 + |s33|^2 + |s43|^2 <= 1 (should be close to 1 if low loss)
    # |s41|^2 + |s42|^2 + |s43|^2 + |s44|^2 <= 1 (should be close to 1 if low loss)
    # |sji|^2 <= 1   ;; equivalent to sjidb <= 0
```

### An attempt in MATLAB

```
    %% fbnd.m
    function F = fbnd(x)
        mr1=[0.016748068572860958+0.02165573563670993j
            0.3524499197684044+1.01318272809286j
            0.9902384965572285-0.4090088119125726j
            0.9902384965572285-0.4090088119125726j
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j
            0.8481899405540196-0.6521365553445038j
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j
            0.8483474812536963-0.6520564750063542j
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j
            0.844854651665744-0.6565142490941961j
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j
            0.8596032944139899-0.6370905579072205j
            0.12178304066817838+0.23419002409258938j
            0.25810610017732+0.11233917791430391j
            -0.7881852138612478+0.2941231164148775j
            0.8537371705084078+0.46722896692551863j
            0.14050135652671147+0.3073232683089746j
            0.09456025715651947+0.3638487655929115j
            0.7994228601750994+0.36132988231302926j
            -0.5729577316366177+0.3829110562916974j];
        mr2=[0.01886638946281557+0.02291153736938316j
            0.41115632130362006+0.9904544135078267j
            -1.0602110266293787+0.12873002023570793j
            -1.0602110266293787+0.12873002023570793j
            0.12178304066817838+0.23419002409258938j
            0.25810610017732+0.11233917791430391j
            -0.7881852138612478+0.2941231164148775j
            0.8537371705084078+0.46722896692551863j
            0.14050135652671147+0.3073232683089746j
            0.09456025715651947+0.3638487655929115j
            0.7994228601750994+0.36132988231302926j
            -0.5729577316366177+0.3829110562916974j
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j
            0.8481899405540196-0.6521365553445038j
            0.8639480592070746-0.6312186830903206j
            0.8483474812536963-0.6520564750063542j
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j
            0.844854651665744-0.6565142490941961j
            0.8599389505285947-0.6367147924208255j
            0.8596032944139899-0.6370905579072205j];
        ms11p=[-0.06420852176004949+0.007606136138496574j
              -0.537896794882235+0.4041100722456898j
              0.1412012055714567+0.5635279161255173j
              0.1937727600367866+0.4292234886620929j
              0.1469515332766462+0.5314862612846253j
              0.1518709241016716+0.5310052159365275j
              0.1578520689668907+0.5331598663019053j
              0.1540581804228726+0.5392467784421259j
              0.1431331385368337+0.5325073157781589j
              0.1535928910517443+0.5342246999907136j
              0.1512448255547076+0.5392322097605335j
              0.1473241418663376+0.5318193110512432j
              -0.2363809027693515+0.1174058767406709j
              -0.163391416393593+0.08774117501580507j
              -0.4568108580888767-0.2143100180166485j
              0.193345944206058-0.04761628164099008j
              -0.237571999125396+0.1195031741294373j
              -0.2034191332391219+0.1681349627984851j
              0.03011118465025885-0.09412680418431373j
              -0.04464063283385059+0.3528230797332958j];
        ms21p=[-0.003180197204485371-0.002823666341755482j
              -0.1906367035405745+0.0686968862920421j
              -0.05526246736964503+0.02635489796438511j
              0.002518013584325512+0.06590835456839306j
              -0.03537661863079149+0.08706407624479129j
              -0.01805052294769753+0.08243849033759301j
              -0.07056927627440178+0.03869620150023408j
              0.02738173375006136+0.04029812368020189j
              -0.02971165660146774+0.08491907637374546j
              -0.02737424760484992+0.09187392180460466j
              0.001038602543646932+0.03696165082008047j
              0.01181224381379054+0.1271817903117702j
              -0.03214857971468995+0.1284805218320462j
              -0.01717410586879602+0.1297380448848506j
              -0.03433798336733016+0.06369364773628092j
              0.043654417400282+0.1396753864320528j
              -0.03468050284302436+0.1289630391584528j
              -0.03705274246077175+0.1366485542793229j
              0.02030699854620357+0.1217902270543576j
              -0.0236005339029794+0.1770862461678967j];
        ms22p=[-0.1624942212974896-0.004693967380702952j
              -0.284542316854743-0.7064738951728178j
              0.4536543123936424-0.4578177740567013j
              -0.1024338501849106-0.1979272945233151j
              -0.1097995580875526-0.198389196010508j
              -0.07902213390718082-0.08677717201029744j
              0.3602007967821697-0.4162898752449462j
              0.1822099768155973+0.3712680606767835j
              -0.09809454238916153-0.1552338582896147j
              -0.1688279742308047-0.115960920204985j
              0.2331637616249181+0.1528931729845114j
              -0.4800053258074745+0.09873053685139994j
              -0.7738872200476685-0.04023055998635539j
              -0.7721863083906342-0.02871292187380659j
              -0.7821436668003945-0.03478684929877463j
              -0.7693920578775125-0.04497757228074708j
              -0.7737959107116188-0.03930039783428967j
              -0.7721735572720234-0.03995110444341842j
              -0.7729703027226912-0.04204217380573128j
              -0.766856877704361-0.04045169338481738j];
        F = zeros(60);



        for n=1:length(ms22p)
            r1 = mr1(n);
            r2 = mr2(n);
            s11p = ms11p(n);
            s21p = ms21p(n);
            s22p = ms22p(n);

            s11db = x(1);
            s21db = x(2);
            s22db = x(3);
            s31db = x(4);
            s32db = x(5);
            s33db = x(6);
            s41db = x(7);
            s42db = x(8);
            s43db = x(9);
            s44db = x(10);

            s11ph = x(11);
            s21ph = x(12);
            s22ph = x(13);
            s31ph = x(14);
            s32ph = x(15);
            s33ph = x(16);
            s41ph = x(17);
            s42ph = x(18);
            s43ph = x(19);
            s44ph = x(20);

            s = @(db,ph) 10.^(db/10) * exp(1j*ph);

            index = 3*(n-1)+1;
            F(index) = ((s(s11db,s11ph) * (1 - (s(s43db,s43ph) * r2 * s(s43db,s43ph) * r1 + s(s33db,s33ph) * r1 + s(s44db,s44ph) *  r2) ...
                + (s(s33db,s33ph) * r1 * s(s44db,s44ph) * r2)) + s(s31db,s31ph) * r1 * s(s31db,s31ph) * (1-(s(s44db,s44ph) * r2)) ...
                + s(s31db,s31ph) * r1 * s(s43db,s43ph) * r2 * s(s41db,s41ph) + s(s41db,s41ph) * r2 * s(s41db,s41ph) * (1-( s(s33db,s33ph) * r1)) ...
                + s(s41db,s41ph) * r2 * s(s43db,s43ph) * r1 * s(s31db,s31ph)) / (1 - (s(s43db,s43ph) *  r2 * s(s43db,s43ph) * r1 ...
                + s(s33db,s33ph) * r1 + s(s44db,s44ph) * r2) + (s(s33db,s33ph) * r1 * s(s44db,s44ph) * r2))) - s11p;
            index = 3*(n-1)+2;
            F(index) = ((s(s32db,s32ph)*r1*s(s31db,s31ph)*(1-(s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+0)+s(s32db,s32ph)*r1*s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s41db,s41ph)+s(s42db,s42ph)*r2 ...
                   *s(s41db,s41ph)*(1-(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1))+s(s42db,s42ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1*s(s31db,s31ph)+s(s21db,s21ph)*(1 ...
                   -(s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1+s(s33db,s33ph)*r1+s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1*s(s44db,s44ph)*r2))) / (1 ...
                   -(s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1+s(s33db,s33ph)*r1+s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1*s(s44db,s44ph)*r2))) - s21p;
            index = 3*(n-1)+3;
            F(index) = ((s(s32db,s32ph)*r1*s(s32db,s32ph)*(1-(s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+0)+s(s32db,s32ph)*r1*s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s42db,s42ph)*(1-0+0)+s(s22db,s22ph)*(1 ...
                   -(s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1+s(s33db,s33ph)*r1+s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1*s(s44db,s44ph)*r2))+s(s42db,s42ph)*r2* ...
                   s(s42db,s42ph)*(1-(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1)+0)+s(s42db,s42ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1*s(s32db,s32ph)*(1-0+0)) / (1 ...
                   -(s(s43db,s43ph)*r2*s(s43db,s43ph)*r1+s(s33db,s33ph)*r1+s(s44db,s44ph)*r2)+(s(s33db,s33ph)*r1*s(s44db,s44ph)*r2))) - s22p;
        end
    end

    %% solve.m
    lb = -80* [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    ub = 2*pi* [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
    guesses = [-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,-40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective',...
        'MaxIterations',5000,...
        'Display','Iter-detailed'...
    );
    %$[x,res] = lsqnonlin(@fbnd,guesses,lb,ub,options);
    optionsf = optimoptions(@fsolve,'Algorithm','trust-region',...
        'Diagnostics','on')
    [x,res] = fsolve(@fbnd,guesses)
```

## Expected Results

I'm expecting/hoping to get a solution within the bounds I've specified (i.e. a reasonable solution). I'm not sure I'm using the right tool for the job, or that I'm correctly using the tools that I'm using currently. If someone could be so kind as to point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.